# Site_url giving wrong address in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have given following `base_url`:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project/';
```

I have following index.php:

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

Now as per above two entries in config file, the site_url should be:

```
http://localhost/project/index.php
```

I am currently on a page `http://localhost/project/index.php/question/get?id=2` which displays a question. Now using a form I am adding questions to it:

```
    <form method="POST" action="<?php site_url(); ?>answer/post_answer" id="post_answer">
```

But the url I am getting in action attribute is:

```
http://localhost/project/index.php/question/answer/post_answer
```

Shouldn't it be:

```
http://localhost/project/index.php/answer/post_answer
```

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: i would use base_url()

Comment: any specific reason for using base_url()? I think base_url is used for assets like display.

Comment: It's just what a lot of the tutorials have had and what I have been told on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `echo` to use `site_url()` value

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo site_url(); ?>answer/post_answer" id="post_answer">
```

Comment: I just discovered the same solution. Thanks by the way. But can you please explain me why it was working without echo.

Comment: You can read any article related to embedding `php` in html : https://www.ntchosting.com/encyclopedia/scripting-and-programming/php/php-in/